# How to launch command on localhost with fabric2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

Here is my script :

```
from fabric2 import Connection

c = Connection('127.0.0.1')
with c.cd('/home/bussiere/'):
    c.run('ls -l')
```

But i have this error :

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

So how do I run a command on localhost ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fabric2, the `Connection` object has got a `local()` method.
Have a look at this object's documentation [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.2/api/connection.html).

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2020, with fabric2 if you don't pass argument to your task decorator by default you are on the local machine.

for example the following will run on your local machine (localhost) :

Example 1 : Only on local

```py
#python3
#fabfile.py


from fabric import task, Connection
c = Connection('remote_user@remote_server.com')


@task
def DetailList(c):
    c.run('ls -l') # will run on local server because the decorator @task does not contain the hosts parameter
```

You then would run this on your machine with

```
fab DetailList
```

If you want to mix code that should be running on remote server and on local you should pass the connection to the @task decorator as a parameter.

Example 2: on local and on remote (but different functions)

```py
#python3
#fabfile.py

#imports
from fabric import task, Connection

#variables
list_of_hosts = ['user@yourserver.com'] #you should have already configure the ssh access
c = Connection(list_of_hosts[0])

working_dir = '/var/www/yourproject'

#will run on remote
@task(hosts = list_of_hosts)
def Update(c):
    c.run('sudo apt get update') # will run on remote server because hosts are passed to the task decorator
    c.run(f'cd {working_dir} && git pull') # will run on remote server because hosts are passed to the task decorator
    c.run('sudo service apache2 restart') # will run on remote server because hosts are passed to the task decorator

#will run on local because you do not specify a host
@task
def DetailsList(c):
    c.run('ls -l') # # will run on local server because hosts are NOT passed to the task decorator
```

As mentionned by Ismaïl there also is a 'local' method that can be used when passing the hosts parameter, the 'local' method will run on the localhost although you have specified the host parameter to the task decorator. Be careful though you can not use the 'local' method if you didn't specified any hosts parameters, use run instead as shown in example 1 & 2.

Example 3 : use both on remote and local servers but under the same functions, note we are not decorating functions that are called in the UpdateAndRestart function.

```py
#python3
#fabfile.py

#imports
from fabric import task, Connection

#variables
list_of_hosts = ['www.yourserver.com'] #you should have already configure the ssh access
c = Connection(list_of_hosts[0])
working_dir = '/var/www/yourproject'


def UpdateServer(c):
    c.run('sudo apt get update') # will run on remote server because hosts are passed to the task decorator
    c.local('echo the remote server is now updated') # will run on local server because you used the local method when hosts are being passed to the decorator


def PullFromGit(c):
    c.run(f'cd {working_dir} && git pull')  # will run on remote server because hosts are passed to the task decorator
    c.local('echo Git repo is now pulled')   # will run on local server because you used the local method when hosts are being passed to the decorator


def RestartServer(c):
    c.run('sudo service apache2 restart') # will run on remote server because hosts are passed to the task decorator
    c.local('echo Apache2 is now restarted') # will run on local server because you used the local method when hosts are being passed to the decorator

    
@task(hosts = list_of_hosts)
def UpdateAndRestart(c):
    UpdateServer(c)
    PullFromGit(c)
    RestartServer(c)
    c.local('echo you have updated, pulled and restarted Apache2') # will run on local server because you used the local method when hosts are being passed to the decorator
```

You will be able to run the entire stack with :

```
fab UpdateAndRestart
```